# Context within express-graphql returns a function

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

I'm trying to create an authentication strategy using context within express-graphql, however, when I access context within `isAuthenticated` it returns `[Function: context]`. What am I not understanding?

```
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP(async (req: any) => ({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
    context: (req: any) => {
      const user = users.find((user) => user.username === "test user");

      if (!user) {
        return {
          message: "Incorrect username or password.",
        };
      }

      return {
        user: "test user",
        active: "Yes",
      };
    },
  }))
);

const isAuthenticated =
  () =>
  (next: any) =>
  async (root: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => {
    console.log("context", context);
    if (!context.currentUser) {
      throw new Error("You are not authorized");
    }
    return next(root, args, context, info);
  };
```

Comment: it seem like your middleware is not being invoked in correct order -- 
i.e., context should be set when `isAuthenticated` called? Apollo server 3 for eg requires you to apply middleware after calling `start` (async): `server.start().then(() => server.applyMiddleware({ app })`. something similar may be culprit. To simplify matters is there any reason all auth logic can't be implemented in context fn (this itself can be`async`). Might be difficult if you need resolver-specific auth policies; if that's the case I'd check out `graphql-shield`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an advice I got from Samer Buna in his book titled "GraphQL in Action":

> Don't do authentication within GraphQL resolving logic. It's better to
> have a different layer handling it either before or after the GraphQL
> service layer.

Can you try something like this

```
server.use("/", (req, res) => {
  //currentUser logic here

  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    context: { currentUser },
  })(req, res);
});
```

Comment: How to get the same user in Resolvers (context:{req, res}?

Comment: resolve methods has a third argument named context